# Factorize values across dataframe columns with consistent mappings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

How can I use pandas `factorize` with values that exist across two columns?

Specifically, I am trying to convert values that exist in two columns to numeric values, and put the corresponding factorized values into new columns, such that the factorization is consistent with the two input columns 'A' and 'B'.

Existing DataFrame:

```
     A   B
0    a   b
1    c   a
2    d   a
3    e   c
4    c   b
5    b   e
6    e   f
```

Desired Output:

```
     A   B   A_ID  B_ID 
0    a   b     0     4
1    c   a     1     0
2    d   a     2     0
3    e   c     3     1
4    c   b     1     4
5    b   e     4     3
6    e   f     3     5
```

I am able to use `factorize` successfully for one column using:

```
df['A_ID'] = pd.factorize(df.A)[0]
```

How could I accomplish this with consistent mappings for values across two columns? Do I need to resort to using a custom `lambda` function instead, or is there a way to accomplish this with `factorize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.factorize`, `apply` + `pd.Categorical`:

```
_, b = pd.factorize(df.values.T.reshape(-1, ))  
                           # or df.values.ravel('F'), as suggested by Zero
r = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, b).codes).add_suffix('_ID')

   A_ID  B_ID
0     0     4
1     1     0
2     2     0
3     3     1
4     1     4
5     4     3
6     3     5

pd.concat([df, r], 1)

   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     4
1  c  a     1     0
2  d  a     2     0
3  e  c     3     1
4  c  b     1     4
5  b  e     4     3
6  e  f     3     5
```

Comment: I like the use of numpy reshaping in this solution.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Returned with interest :-)

Comment: You could do `df.values.ravel('F')` inplace of `df.values.T.reshape(-1, )` aswell

Comment: @Zero That's nifty! Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, this works well. I updated the question with an additional column 'C.' Therefore, this works for me when I use `df[['A', 'B']]`  in lines 1 and 2 of your solution, instead of `df` to account for and include this additional column 'C' in the DataFrame. Would that be the optimal way to solve for this case?

Comment: @GabeF. Yes, it's perfectly alright - you're just taking the columns you need, instead of every column.

Comment: Constructing new Categorical for every row, is quite an overkill. If you just replace the lambda statement with: `b.get_loc(x)`, instead of `pd.Categorical(x, b).codes` it'll be much faster.

Comment: @JonanGeorgiev it isn't done for every row, it is done twice - once for each column, since the default is `axis=0`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, if you want to reuse factorize values.

```
In [2637]: facts = np.unique(np.unique(df[['A', 'B']]), return_index=True)

In [2638]: mapping = dict(zip(*facts))

In [2639]: df.join(df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x.map(mapping)).add_suffix('_ID'))
Out[2639]:
   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     1
1  c  a     2     0
2  d  a     3     0
3  e  c     4     2
4  c  b     2     1
5  b  e     1     4
6  e  f     4     5
```

---

**Or,** using `replace`

```
In [2640]: df.join(df[['A', 'B']].replace(mapping).add_suffix('_ID'))
Out[2640]:
   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     1
1  c  a     2     0
2  d  a     3     0
3  e  c     4     2
4  c  b     2     1
5  b  e     1     4
6  e  f     4     5
```

---

And, to **preserve** your order of values use

```
In [2]: mapping = dict(zip(*pd.factorize(df['A'].append(df['B']).drop_duplicates())[::-1]))

In [2]: mapping
Out[2666]: {'a': 0, 'b': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 5}

In [3]: df.join(df[['A', 'B']].replace(mapping).add_suffix('_ID'))
Out[3]:
   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     4
1  c  a     1     0
2  d  a     2     0
3  e  c     3     1
4  c  b     1     4
5  b  e     4     3
6  e  f     3     5
```

---

**Details**

```
In [2641]: facts
Out[2641]:
(array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype=object),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64))

In [2642]: mapping
Out[2642]: {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zero, this works for my original question where all values in Column B are also present in Column A. I updated the question where Column B has a value that is not in Column A. How could I solve for that case? Currently, `B_ID` will return `NaN` in that case, as the value does not exist in `facts`. Also, on my system, `B_ID` values are coming back as doubles (4.0, 0.0, ...). How can I cast them to int during this process, to match `A_ID`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `apply`, `add_suffix` with `pd.factorize` and `assign`:

```
f = pd.factorize(df.stack().drop_duplicates().sort_index(level=1))
s1 = pd.Series(f[0], index=f[1])
print(df.assign(**df.apply(lambda x: x.map(s1)).add_suffix('_ID')))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     1
1  c  a     2     0
2  d  a     3     0
3  e  c     4     2
4  c  b     2     1
5  b  e     1     4
```

## Ouput with updated dataset:

```
   A  B  A_ID  B_ID
0  a  b     0     4
1  c  a     1     0
2  d  a     2     0
3  e  c     3     1
4  c  b     1     4
5  b  e     4     3
6  e  f     3     5
```