# Factorize real time data with consistent mappings to training data?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

In production level, I would like to use the beforehand-saved model to predict my real-time data.

However, I don't know how to set my real time data to have a consistent mapping with training data when factorizing categorical data.

[From this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761978/factorize-values-across-dataframe-columns-with-consistent-mappings) I know I can stack training data & new data together and make them consistent.

However, stacking and going through the whole process (doing the whole feature engineering, training and prediction) is too time consuming.

- Whole process:15 mins **v.s.** model.prediction only: 3 sec

As the production level system is time sensitive, is there any method that I can use to factorize the new data to have the same mapping as training data?

Or can I only do it by «manually», such as

```
 df.loc[df['col_name']=='YES', 'col_name'] =  '1'
```

which could lead to very long coding?

Comment: I found an alternative tool, LabelEncoder, of pd.factorize. Let me try and report the effect if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is accounting for novel categorical values as they come in (say, you get a new value of 'blue-green' for df.color), you could bounce any unexpected values to the same -1 bucket (unknown, let's say) and then handle that in post-processing or whenever it is that you re-tune the model.

Essentially, you could catch the category-exceptions and then handle them later on.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of work, I switch from pd.factorize to LabelEncoder().
As LabelEncoder only supports pd.series data, I tried to use a loop to go through all columns and store each LabelEncoder() fitted model to a dictionary.

In training data part

```
# list you want to do Label encoding
col_list =  ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']
df[col_list]= df[col_list].fillna('NAN')

# create  a dictionary to save LabelEncoder() model for each col
model = {}

# convert Categorical Data
for x in col_list:
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    df[x]=encoder.fit_transform(df.__getattr__(x))
    model[x]= encoder

# save dictionary to pickle file
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

In real-time data part :

```
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model= pickle.load(f)

for x in col_list:
    encoder = model[x]
    try:
        df[x]=encoder.transform(df[x].astype(str))
    except:
        df[x]=encoder.transform(df[x].astype(int))
```

As result it cost me 1.5 sec to load the data, do feature engineering and prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Which algorithm are you using? I have come accross the same problem, but since I am using a LGBM, it turns out there is no need to factorize my data, the algorithm can handle catergorised values. I had to change the data type from 'object' to 'category'.

```
categorical_feats = [f for f in combined_data.columns if combined_data[f].dtype == 'object']

categorical_feats
for f_ in categorical_feats:
    # Set feature type as categorical
    combined_data[f_] = combined_data[f_].astype('category')
```